# Broken datetime on CloudSQL + Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql

So I had a lot of problems with datetimes in Django on the App Engine, but then I started tracing the error and seems like there's more serious problems. Here's what I'm seeing.

Here's my database:

```
mysql> select * from polls_question;
+----+---------------+----------------------------+
| id | question_text | pub_date                   |
+----+---------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | test          | 2016-02-08 15:24:44.000000 |
+----+---------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

And here's the code trying to read this data:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import webapp2

class IndexPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    env = os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE')
    if (env and env.startswith('Google App Engine/')):
    # Connecting from App Engine
      db = MySQLdb.connect(
      unix_socket='/cloudsql/<removed>:<removed>',
      user='root',db='gaetest')
    else:
      # Connecting from an external network.
      # Make sure your network is whitelisted
      db = MySQLdb.connect(
      host='<removed>',
      port=3306,
      user='root', passwd='<removed>',db='<removed>')

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM polls_question')
    for r in cursor.fetchall():
      self.response.write('%s\n' % str(r))

    db.close()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexPage),
    ])
```

On my computer it gives me:

```
(1L, 'test', datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 8, 15, 24, 44))
```

and when I access the remote url I get:

```
(1L, 'test', None)
```

Not sure what more I can do, this example is as simplified as it can get. Does anyone have any clue what's going on? Too bad Google is typically impossible to get hold off.

Answer (score 1):

So after having spent way too much time on this I found the problem, the database was created using django's migrate function, which lead to it creating a datetime(6) (high precision), these don't work when accessing the site remotely. Normal datetimes work. So changing those makes it work.

The cause of the problem was when I used a newer mysql-python lib locally which supported datetime(6).

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug with App Engine library MySQLdb 1.2.4b4, which at time of writing is also "latest". Switching the app.yaml dependency for MySQLdb from "latest" or "1.2.4b4" to "1.2.5" or "1.2.4" should fix the issue.